# Inserting Text Into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, text

What I Want: Very simply I have a C program that generates a variable periodically, I want to be able to display this value on a website.

Restrictions: The webpage is HTML, php does not work, javascript does [I have tried a few javascript solutions but they have all been long, tedious and in the end ineffective] I want it to be able to format the text so that it matches the rest of the webpage. Above all I'd really like to find something simple that works.

Freedoms: I can output the variable from my C program to just about any file type and content that I want, the file is hosted so is available locally to the server or online for the client.

Preferred Solutions: I am currently playing around with the object and iframe tags native to html. They give a nice simple input:

```
<object height=20 width=75 type='text/plain' border=0 data="URL/filename.txt"></object>
```

inserts the contents of my file, but it can't be formatted so I am stuck with 12pt Courier font which is not acceptable. Using

```
<iframe seamless height=20 width=75 scrolling='no' src="URL/filename.htm"></iframe>
```

and adding my desired font/colour/size etc to the htm file gets me the right text style, but htm has a large amount of white padding around it which I can't seem to get rid of so I have to make my iframe quite large for the text to be displayed, but then it doesn't fit smoothly with other text.

So anyone that can answer one of four questions:

- How to remove excess padding from htm
- How to format the style of a html object
- Is there anything in Java as simple as the php [so apparently it doesn't show php code even when you quote it as code. But basically using echo and get_file_contents to insert the contents of a txt file into a html page]
- Propose an alternate solution

Comment: *"php does not work, javascript does"* I think you're mistaken what PHP and JS are used for.

Comment: @m0skit0 I think he's got that part right.  He has a static HTML page.

Comment: You don't want Java, you want JavaScript... they are very different things.  In the context of Web Development, Java is a server-side technology just like PHP.

Comment: *Javascript, it was a typo. Something I thought of is that I could perhaps have my C program output the variables directly into a .js file which is loaded by the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Padding and style can be handled by [css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/).

By `java` I assume you mean `javascript` - google-ing will help you. Without details of what your server is running and what is dispatching your pages we can't give you an exact answer. You might want something with [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to keep it updating in the background.

Try googling your question, you'd be surprised how often this helps.

Comment: *javascript that was a typo.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the specifics of my server or what its running, its a Linux server, with apache, javascript, php5 and anything else I care to add. However the source code for my webpage was not written by me hence I want to disturb it as little as possible. I read that php only works if the file has an extension of .php which I can't do without breaking other links. Google is surprisingly quiet on this, I've tried the top 5 or 6 solutions so will keep digging

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do once you get the variable into your web page, but I think something like the following could be useful.

- Create a hidden div on your page
- Have your C application write the variable to some file
- Use jquery to execute an ajax call to pull that value into the div ( or whatever other container you want to use
- using some type of timer, execute the ajax call every X period of time, which will then get your up to date variable
- on your main page, have another timer that will then come in to that container, grab your value and then you are free to do what you want with it.

This is all off the top of my head without knowing much about what you're trying to accomplish. If you provide some further details we may be able to help you a little more.

Comment: Over thinking it, the variable only needs to be loaded once with the page load its sufficient just to hit refresh to get a new value

AJAX solutions seem to be excessive for what I need, one code example I used was a full screen of code to retrieve 5 digits (and ultimately didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

You need AJAX... that's just a fancy buzz-word.  It means you can tell JavaScript can get a file from the server without reloading the page and you can insert data from that file into your HTML.

AJAX is made much simpler by using a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), but it can be done without jQuery.  There's a pretty decent [Getting Started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) tutorial at Mozilla Developer Network if you want to do it the hard way, but I really recommend jQuery.

As far as formatting... any formatting... you need to use CSS.  Just about everything about the appearance of anything on a web page is controlled by CSS.  MDN has a [Learn CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css) section, too.

Comment: I will look into that CSS link to see if it helps.

Comment: Didn't end up going as far as a separate CSS file, but I added styling to the htm header. I had to set padding and margins for both 'p' and 'body' to get it tight to the text, but working well now. Embedded the pages inside my main page using iframes with carefully selected size and no borders/padding. Still amazed there is no easy way to get html to read from a local file.

Answer (score -1):

1. load jquery on you main html file
2. put a div with some id (example id="newvalue")
3. make you c program to write the output in a file (for example value.html)
4. on main html page header, after jquery include code add some javascript like

   $( document ).ready(function() {
       $("#newvalue").load('yoursiteurl/value.html');
   });